# How to avoid injecting uninitialized dependencies?

Tags: dependency-injection, ioc-containers

I have some components which require some asynchronous calls to be finished before those components are fully initialized and ready for work.

I do not want dependant objects to know about these lifetime issues of their dependencies.

How do you manage that?

Comment: How does your language deal with asynchronous things generally? E.g. the container could expose a future/promise of when it's finished resolving all the dependencies, then it can resolve those individual async initialisations as part of that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am talking about C#, async/await. In fact I am working on a Unity3D game and we use Zenject for DI.

Comment: You can inject a proxy instead. The dependant always gets something injected no matter the state of the element being wrapped.

Comment: @Laiv From my point of view, that's the right answer for all the use cases I can imagine right now. You should post it as an answer. The proxy can also be used to accommodate any logic regarding the uninitialised state: Either block the caller until the dependency is finished with its async task or throw an exception or delegate to some other temporary mock depenceny or something else entirely

Comment: I started to write one, but as I was writing, I couldn't stop thinking I was missing something important the OP has not "transmitted" clearly. I thought I was being too simplistic.

Comment: @AntonPetrov what would you say is your main concern? Initialize the dependency graph immediately without locking? Avoid lockings at all cost?

Comment: @Laiv imagine your class Foo depends on some IBar interface and receives it through Foo() constructor. But the problem is you cannot use IBar immediately because its implementation Bar requires some "long" async initialization. This is a problem. And I think that long async initialization is an implementation detail and we should not force it through IBar interface.

Comment: You are right. You need a proxy then. The proxy behaves like IBar from the caller standpoint, but also as a facade to hide the async initialization. Making Ibar somewhat lazy initializable too.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create the dependent objects until the dependency's initialization finishes.

Then there is no such problem. The dependent object always sees the dependency as initialized.

Of course, now you can't create the whole object graph synchronously.

Answer (score 1):

Design your own dependencies. Initialize them fully in the constructor. If ever you get stuck with only part of what you need then create a class that only takes that part. Shove it in something else when you get the rest.

Do it this way and everything that exists is ready to be used.  Yes it forces you to think up more names for more classes but you don’t have to check if things are ready. If it exists, it’s ready.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at builder pattern and try to employ that.
Basically, you do not want to have the dependent classes to worry about dependencies being initialized. Rather, put that logic in the builder class and let Builder class worry about that.

Comment: I know what is the Builder pattern but I cannot see how you suggest to use it. You suggest dependent classes to build dependencies using builders for themselves? Usually in IoC environment we use factories to create something...

Comment: Ah, I see. You mean how IHostBuilder works... Then consider if your service A depends on another service B and wants to use it but service B did not finished its initialization yet. Looks like service A must be careful using B and I am trying to avoid this. Otherwise your code gets bloated with 'if's checking that this ir that is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap this nasty implementation detail in a class so the caller doesn't have to worry about it.

Within the class, store the `Task` that was returned when you called the initialization routine, then `await` it before allowing the caller to use any data.

```
class SomeLibrary
{
    private readonly Task _initializationTask;
    private string _data = null;

    public SomeLibrary()
    {
        _initializationTask = InitializeAsync();
    }

    private async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        _data = await GetDataAsync(); //Or whatever
    }

    public async Task<string> GetData()
    {
        await _initializationTask;
        return _data;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work but I do not like here that this design forces a dependant class to be async/awaited too and this will propagate further down the call chain.

Comment: If the caller isn't async, what do you want the caller to do if the initialization isn't complete yet? It either has to wait for the initialization to complete or throw an exception. Do you want it to block the thread?

Comment: So this is the root of my question I guess ))

Comment: @AntonPetrov: It makes no sense to not want to use await, while at the same time trying to await a task. It also makes no sense to both want this logic _not_ in the actual service, and at the same time not want an additional dependent class to contain the logic.

Comment: @Flater I am not "trying to await a task" :) I want to receive a dependency which is ready for work from the moment I received it. But this dependency may require some async initialization. So I cannot just drop everything into a single container. I need some sort of orchestration and I asked about what others do in that case.

Comment: @AntonPetrov: _" I am not trying to await a task :)"_ Note that in this context, "task" and "asynchronous operation" are synonymous. If you want to receive something only when it is ready, and it's not ready yet, then someone has to wait for it to be ready before giving it to you. Which class does the awaiting might still be up for debate, but _that_ you need to await a task is not.

Comment: *So this is the root of my question I guess* You seem to be asking us what your requirements are. Only you can determine the requirements, based (hopefully) on the needs of the people who will be using this stuff. Anything else is just a matter of opinion.